# Can anyone identify this plant that is growing in my yard?

Tags: identification

I have this plant I found and planted. I have it in a pot in my yard. Can anyone identify it?

*<sub>Click for full size</sub>*
[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). Your photo doesn't indicate what size it is. If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I am pretty sure that you have a [poinsettia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poinsettia) variety in your garden. Actually I have seen how these beautiful plants turn the green color of some leaves into red, as you can appreciate it in your own.

Here an example of a wilder poinsettia:

[image]

Comment: The scalloped leaves don't look like a poinsettia

Comment: Not all lettuces have similar leaves, but this kind of poinsettia looks like wilder than others [here an examle](http://www.eoearth.org/files/193601_193700/193700/poinsettia4.jpg)

Comment: It might help if you add the botanical name to your answer, which is Poinsettia cyathophora, and it does resemble that. However, it would be good for 100% certain ID if we could see the actual flowers in the photograph attached to the question clearly - they're out of focus

Comment: @AlexanderDeLeonVI - not sure what you mean by 'lettuce' - that term is applied to an edible, leafy plant used as a salad vegetable, and that's certainly not applicable to Poinsettia, but maybe its a language issue...

Comment: Oh sorry for the missconceptions!, not an expert even not a native speaker, just a plants lover :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a ‘wild’ pointsettia

[image]

I have these growing throughout my yard in San Diego. In my experience, the ones I have are dormant much of the year, and have skinny tallish stems with one or more medium sized ‘flowers’, which are very scalloped in shape and have a fair bit of green on them.